# Conditional ordering for Latin and English Names in SQLite

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have a table 'Employee' which has column **DevId, Id, FName, FNamePinYin**.
FName will have both Chinese and English contact names. Now as per requirement I could manage to get contacts in below order:

```
FName          FNamePinYin
爱华 杨         AIHUA YANG
安国华          ANGUOHUA
Anguohua       ANGUOHUA
Aihua Yang     AIHUA YANG
爸              BA
波 小           BO BEI BI XIAO
毕慧            BIHUI
Bin Guo        BIN GUO
Bihui          BIHUI
Ba             BA
```

Using below query:

```
Select FName, SortString 
from Employee 
where Id in (SELECT Id 
             FROM EMP1
             WHERE '1' = DevId 
             ORDER BY FnamePinYin 
             LIMIT 500 OFFSET 0) 
ORDER BY substr(FnamePinYin,1,1) , Lower(FName) DESC
```

Now the problem is that contact names are not sorted in ascending order.

Note: Here Lower(FName) DESC is required to get Chinese names to be displayed first in each alphabet's category.

**My desired output:**

```
FName          FNamePinYin
爱华 杨         AIHUA YANG
安国华          ANGUOHUA
Aihua Yang     AIHUA YANG
Anguohua       ANGUOHUA
爸             BA
波 小           BO BEI BI XIAO
毕慧            BIHUI
Ba             BA
Bihui          BIHUI
Bin Guo        BIN GUO
```

FNamePinYin is English equivalent of Chinese names.

Can anyone help me get the result I want?

Comment: Normally, the solution would be to use a case-insensitive collation. But SQLite doesn't allow case-insensitive collation on anything other than ASCII character sets. I'm not sure if you can sort like you want in the database without using additional plugins. You might be able to do it in your display code. I'd look into the collation route.   REF: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html < Section 7

Comment: Do the Chinese names need to sort with each other?  It doesn't look like it from your desired output since e.g., 爱 > 安 according to Unicode order.  Does it matter?

Comment: @varro Yes in each category (A-Z) corresponding Chinese names should come and then English. And both Chinese and English Name should be in Acceding order. At present I am getting them in descending order. 爱 > 安 according to Unicode order. We can consider FNamePinYin to sort Chinese Names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still not entirely clear, but based on your statement that "both Chinese and English Name should be in Acceding order" "in each category (A-Z)", then the following should do what I *think* you want:

```
 select * 
 from Employee 
 where Id in (SELECT Id 
         FROM PBAPL1 
         WHERE '1' = DevId 
         ORDER BY FnamePinYin 
         LIMIT 500 OFFSET 0)
 order by substr(FNamePinYin,1,1), (substr(FName,1,1) < 'zz'), FName;
```